# Performing a function against an observable array of objects, given an array of object ids

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Given the following array of ids:

```
var arrayOfIds = ko.observableArray(["2", "3"]);
```

And the following array of objects:

```
var arrayOfObjects = ko.observableArray([
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Test Folder",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Test Folder",
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Test Folder",
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "Test Folder",
    },
])
```

How can I efficiently perform an action on only those objects specified in the id array?

Specifically, I'm trying to do:

```
arrayOfObjects.remove(<items 2 and 3 from the id array>).
```

What I have:

```
arrayOfObjects.remove(function (item) {
                return arrayOfIds().contains(item.id);
            });
```

But I can't use "contains" on an array...

I also tried this:

```
innerModel.folders.remove(function (item) {
                return $.inArray(item.id, selectedFolders()) > 0;
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a callback function that accepts an array item, it will iterate through items and will remove those where you return `true`.

```
arrayOfObjects.remove(function (item){
    return item.id === '2' || item.id === '3';
});
```

Or use the jQuery [`inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function to check against many values:

```
arrayOfObjects.remove(function (item){
    var itemsToRemove = ['2','1','4','7'];
    return  $.inArray(item.id, itemsToRemove) !== -1;
});
```

Comment: I tried this but I need to use an array of Ids, not specified ids.  Updated my post to show what I'm trying

Comment: Ok, see updated answer. You will still need to have knowledge what items should be removed.

Comment: Thanks Tomas.  Any thoughts on the performance of this compared to the solution I posted in an answer?

Comment: InArray check will perform much better, because you will need to loop only once over your folders array, and loop over integers or strings array will be faster, I'm assuming that it will also be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(arrayOfIds(), function (folderId) {
                arrayOfObjects.remove(function (folder) {
                    if (folder.folderId() === folderId) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
```